# Add article software for my website

Tags: web-development

I have been writing my website by hand for a long time, using Gedit(On Ubuntu). Recently I have discovered sublime text, which works great, but I still write it by hand.

Now I am looking for something like [this](http://fidelvanegas.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/addNewArticle0.1Post.png), which is a wordpress add article feature/plugin/??

But I don't want the entire Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla software, I want an add article software on my website, which I can edit to fit my needs.

(edit my websites source code with sublime text at home. add article from home or any where else,)

Comment: Can you code? If yes you could build a solution for yourself pretty easily, using a micro web framework in the language of your choice.

Comment: @elssar I can code, using HTML/CSS(php/javscript i am a beginner in)... what is a "micro web framework"!?

Comment: A microframework is something that helps you build dynamic websites easily. I would suggest googling a bit and checking them out.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the software "Jekyll" for easy blogging without installing a full-blown CMS like Drupal or Wordpress: http://jekyllbootstrap.com/

It requires git to publish pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how much coding do you want to do?

The simplest way would be to use [Zapier](https://zapier.com) to watch for updates on either a folder on your dropbox(or a similar service), or if you use github, then look for a a new gist. When that even occurs, call a url on your site, which will then pull the post to your website. For example, you could [this recipe](https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/webhook/5730/new-gists-sends-post-request/) on Zapier to sent a post request when a new Gist is detected.

Another way could be to take Zapier out of the equation, and send the post request yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want front end as your wish , you are not interested to use CMS for your for your front end but you need to manage the content @ the backend using any tool....

You Install the wordpress in your server in any folder like /blog or /cms and add some article using wp-admin

Use php or any web scripting language fetch the records from the wp database and display in your website

Am also using the same method refer my website http://asvignesh.in/blog_all_titles.php